# What can be done to make a transmutation seem real even to magical senses?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, polymorph, divination, disguise

## The core problem

For characters living in a world where high level and possibly epic casters (without the Epic Spellcasting feat) exist, passing for the creature they're polymorphed into is hard.

A simple true sight effect (through the spell or any item that replicates its effects) sees through the illusory or polymorphed shape and reveals the caster's true form.

While there are ways to hide the caster's true form, such as a Cowl of Warding or any effect that makes your real shape impossible to divine, not seeing the true form but still recognizing that the form visible to the naked, unaided eye is not the real one is very problematic for it tells the true sight spellcasters that something is amiss and worth investigating.

My aim is to find ways to polymorph into any creature and hide the fact that the resulting shape is not my natural form.

### What works and why am I looking for something better or different.

- 7 levels in Spymaster (Complete Adventurer): I don't care about anything else Spymaster does. Also, I have a limit on the number of classes I can use, so if I don't have to rely on a Prestige Class to do this one thing I can take another that does things I like more.
- Many ranks in disguise: using disguise to look like a wildly different creature breaks my immersion, it also has height limitations.
- Cloak of Khyber spell, from the Eberron setting: the game only uses a set of manuals, listed below, that doesn't include this spell. Otherwise, it'd be perfect.
- Insidious Magic feat: doesn't work against shadow weave users, lowers my caster level for transmutation spells, makes me even more MAD (15 Wis prerequisite for Shadow Weave Magic on a character that wants high Cha, Int and Con) and magic items aren't helping me get to the required score because (for background reasons) I would need to take Shadow Weave Magic by level 6 at most.

### Why I want it

In case it helps finding alternative ways to do it, I'm trying to...

- do things such as to infiltrate an enemy organization or make enemies think an ally is in one place but it's really me impersonating them;
- go around in a different shape than mine while not making all guards suspicious about why I'm doing that; how I choose to look is none of their business.

### Level range

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this at level 20, the level I'm starting the game at.

If it comes online later, so be it: I can theoretically reach level 36, but the earlier it happens, the better.

### The build

My choice of classes up to level 20 is set in stone:

- Sorcerer 5
- Mindbender 1
- Incantatrix 3
- Warshaper 3
- Master Transmogrifist 8

Later, my plan is this:

- Master Transmmogrifist 2 (10) - to get the Infinite Variety capstone as quickly as possible
- Incantatrix 4 (7) - to reach level 9 spells for Shapechange as quickly as possible

Then for the last 10 levels...

- maybe finishing Incantatrix and then getting into Spymaster (sigh) if I really have no other option;
- maybe getting 10 levels in Chameleon to be even better at impersonating people with all of Chameleon's fake class features;
- maybe getting just 2 levels of Chameleon (the variable feat is useful to impersonate people) and then one more warshaper level and finally more Incantatrix and sorcerer levels to raise my caster level.

I am limited to 6 different classes and I have already set in stone the first 5.

My mandatory feats, including the human bonus feat, are:

- Able Learner (necessary for managing skill points early in the build, also doubles as Chameleon prerequisite if I choose to go that way)
- Iron Will (Incantatrix prerequisite)
- Extend Spell (Incantatrix prerequisite, since I want to get Persist Spell)
- Eschew materials (Master transmogrifist prerequisite)
- Persist Spell (bonus from Incantatrix)
- Minor Shapeshift (too cool to skip)
- Practiced Spellcaster (helps with durations and against dispelling)
- Rapid Metamagic (I have ran out of polymorphing-related feats and Incantatrix will give me more metamagic spells, so I think my backup plan for when polymorphing is ineffective or for when I need to kill something quickly is to buy a rod of quicken and a rod of maximize, have a free hand thanks to *Girallon's Blessing* and blast away or debuff.)

I still have one more feat to choose pre-epic and 6 epic feats to choose.

One of the epic feats will probably be Leadership, which has been houseruled as an epic feat. The cohort won't be a buff-bot.

Most others I expect to be Extra Slot, Improved Metamagic or some non-epic metamagic. I still have to choose my epic feat loadout but first I want to see how many slots are still open after I have solved the problem this question is about.

### Allowed materials and other considerations about the game

Core manuals (only up to MM3)
All Races of splatbooks
All Complete splatbooks
Spell Compendium
All 3e and 3.5e forgotten realms books
Draconomicon
Epic level handbook, except feats
Book of heroic deeds
Lords of madness
Fiendish codex 1 and 2
Planar handbook
Liber mortis (ok, ok, you call it "Libris mortis", I know)
Frostburn
Sandstorm
Stormwrack

Banned content from these books:
Class variants
Racial sub levels
Psionics
Grafts
Artifacts

I will be a regular PHB human.

I am supposed to work with a rotating cast of other PCs, in West Marches style. Needing their help or intervention to overcome my weaknesses is expected and encouraged, so if there is a good solution that requires my character asking some other character's help, this is not just fine, it might be even better.

Comment: You don’t indicate the character’s current ECL; the statement that you cast spells as a 14th-level sorcerer combined with 7 missed spellcasting levels suggests the answer is 21st, but unless I’ve missed it, you don’t actually confirm that anywhere. (Though this question is also rather ramble-y and long, so it’s possible I may have missed it.)

Comment: I omitted details because I didn't think it was important, I'm currenlty ECL20 (sorc 5, mindbender 1, incantatrix 3, warshaper 3, master transmogriffist 8) but I already know that one of the level I'm goin to take (master transmogrifist's last level) won't advance my spellcaster level. (I also plan to take 4 more incantatrix levels). So it's at least 7 levels lost over the total 36 that I can hope to reach someday. I might lose other 10 if I decide to go chameleon 10, or 7 more if I decide to go master spy 7 and then finish Incantatrix, or 5 more if I finish mindbender, etc.: 19 to 29 over 36.

Comment: Your sense of what is or isn’t important to include seems wildly miscalibrated, to me. Important details: current/planned build, source restrictions, goals, and expected level range. Any requirements or preferences that affect answers. Things you’ve considered and why they were rejected can be important but only secondarily so. Unimportant details: backstory, musing about irrelevant build options, anything that doesn’t affect answers, and everything else.

Comment: 1/2 I think I have spent enough words stating my goal: to make it so other characters who can see through magical disguises can't see through mine. I have mentioning having access to epic feats, so everything included epic feats is on the board. Source restrictions have proven hard to talk about because the conversation very often shifts to how stupid the criteria are in the minds of the would-be answerers, so I'd like the answer to assume everything is available, I'll filter out what I can't use but my accept mark won't consider that. Same for the build, but I will edit them into the question

Comment: 2/2 the backstory is important because it shows that I don't just care about mechanically best, I care about solutions that fit who the character is. Suggesting a vile feat would not be interesting. The irrelevant build options are more about showing my work, which is a requirement for questions, but they also serve as examples of what I'm looking for if the description wasn't clear enough. Anyway, I'll try to organize things better. @KRyan

Comment: @KRyan Having reworked the question I'd like to see if it looks better to you. I know the different sections are still floating in place without a train of thoughts to bind them together, but at least one can look at the titles and decide which to pay more attention to (or so I hope).

Comment: Feel free to consider this boring, unhelpful or even inappropriate, but the correct solution to your problem is to get the DM to approve that one spell from Eberron. It is a crucial piece of your character concept. If you're doing an optimization exercise - go ahead, pour through books, ask around, research. For a real game - you already know a solution exists and the DM is either willing to let you bring the character concept to the table, or they are not.

Comment: @martixy Unfortunately this is a mix of a living world and west marches game, with hundreds of players. The staff allowing any of us to get something special would cause all sorts of drama in the playerbase. The available material is what I listed, no more. It would have been better if i had noticed this problem before registering the character, the other option now is to trash this character, lose XP and GP and make another one but losing resources I have worked for because of a mistake I made on my own is psychologically hard on me and I don't want to. I'd rather not impersonate people.

Comment: @martixy in other words imagine me joining a MMORPG and ask the publisher to implement a new power. Why would they?

Comment: I must admit, I missed the fact this is a West Marches game. I have never played in such a setup. The constraints now make a lot more sense in this context. Personally, if this was nagging at me, I would likely just ask to be allowed to fix my mistake. Anyway, apologies for not having any solution for you. When I read the question, the first thing that came to mind was the Khyber spell.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Have you considered investing on **Disguise** (I mean the skill)? Clearly there's no magic can penetrate that, and spellcasters are tend to have low Sense Motive and Spot.

Comment: @TerryWindwalker yes, I have. It's even in the question. It's just that... technically, you can be a huge humanoid and disguise yourself into an hydra but... I'd be  happier if I could avoid something so hard to rationalize.